# error during passing two different queries result to view in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on small programming assignment in which I want to show an image and its related comment like Facebook.

My image is in one table and comments in one table. I am fetching both of them from different tables and I want to pass these results to view. And there I want to show these results according to its related post. But this gives me error. Every comment has its related `post_id` which is actually a `post_id` of post.

Here is my code.

Model:

```
public function load_posts_with_comments(){
    $posts    = image_post::all(); // loading all posts
    $comments = commenting::all(); // loading all comments
    return view('home_page_of_posts', [
        'posts'    => $posts,
        'comments' => $comments
    ]); // passing it to view, there I will do it through for each nested loop but it does not work.
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work like how? The data is not sent to the view? or the comments are not for the posts?

Comment: How you are displaying ? And what error you are getting ?

Comment: i have checked by echoing that the data is correct . but it does not print in correct formate.. it gives the error

Comment: comments exist for post.

Comment: I am fairly confident Facebook doesnt load every single post and comment when displaying a single post....

Answer (score 3):

Create a `hasMany` relationship between posts and comments models if it doesn't exist yet. Somethin like:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Then use `with()` method to load comments related to each post. Something like this will work:

```
public function loadPostsWithComments()
{
    $posts = Post::with('comments')->get();

    return view('home_page_of_posts', compact('posts'));
}
```

Then in Blade template, you can iterate over posts and comments:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
        {{ $comment->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: is there any other option because i am new on laravel.?

Comment: @DANISHTAYYIB you don't need any other option, none of the options are easier. Just read Laravel docs and it will be clearer for you.